# NHibernate updates not persisted

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hibernate-mapping

I have two entities declared like this (much simplified):

```
public Test1 {
    public virtual int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Test2> Childs {get;set;}
}

public Test2 {
    public virtual int Id {get;set;}  
    public virtual Test1 Parent {get;set;}
    public virtual string Name {get;set;}
}    

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="Test" assembly="Test">
  <class name="Test1" table="test1">
    <id name="Id" column="id_parent">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <set name="Childs" table="test2" cascade="save-update" batch-size="10" inverse="true"> 
      <key column="id_parent" not-null="true"/>
      <one-to-many class="Test.Test2, Test" />
    </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>    

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="Test" assembly="Test">
  <class name="Test2" table="test2">
    <id name="Id" column="id_child">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <many-to-one name="Parent" column="id_parent" class="Test.Test1, Test" />

    <property name="Name" column="name" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Now I want to change name property of a (first) child:

```
    var entities = Session.CreateCriteria<Test1>().List<Test1>();
    var tx = Session.BeginTransaction();
    foreach (Test1 entity in entities)
    {
        entity.Childs.First().Name = "blabla";
        Session.Update(entity);
    }
    tx.Commit();
```

But this doesn't work. I can see in NhProf that transaction was started, that sql was fired for fetching parent records, and another one for fetching child records. But no sql was fired for updating name property. What am I doing wrong? I was trying different things when I was reading documentation but with no success.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: try to call session.flush after the foreach...

Comment: Aren't changes flushed with commit? I have also tried to put flush after foreach but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

`ISession.Update` should not be called in the scenario above.  You are working with an attached entity so changes are tracked automatically.  There is no need to explicitly call Update.

Read here for further explanation:
http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-updating-detached

Also it depends on what your flushmode is set to as to when updates occur.  Try setting your flushmode explicitly to Commit in the above example.  Here is a table of flushmodes:

**Auto**
The ISession is sometimes flushed before query execution in order to ensure that queries never return stale state. This is the default flush mode.

**Commit**
The ISession is flushed when Transaction.Commit() is called

**Never**
The ISession is never flushed unless Flush() is explicitly called by the application. This mode is very efficient for read only transactions

So you would end up with something like this:

```
Session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Commit;
var entities = Session.CreateCriteria<Test1>().List<Test1>();

using(var tx = Session.BeginTransaction())
{
    foreach (Test1 entity in entities)
    {
        entity.Childs.First().Name = "blabla";
        Session.Update(entity);
    }

    tx.Commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by removing the `inverse` attribute.  You have `inverse=true`. Try changing it to `false`.